# Display values from an Array for debugging purposes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I show the Array Values in Pine Script for debugging?  Is there a Debug or Print Window that I have not found?

Comment: there is the Data Window, accessed on the right hand side toolbar, however, you have to force data into it sometimes and the de facto for that is _plotchar_ .

Answer (score 2):

Use the following function in v5:

```
printDebug(txt) => 
  var table t = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 1),
                table.cell(t, 0, 0, txt, bgcolor = color.yellow)
```

Depending on the size of your array, you may need to modify the function to accommodate your data - eg add additional cells.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started on the concept.  A Debugging Window or Output Window sure would be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @WeekendHack Agree that a debugging/output window would be useful... but until then....  If this answers your question can you mark it as answered?